# Does ActiveMQ Artemis support master to master failover?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have two ActiveMQ Artemis servers (server1 and server2). Both are the master and there is no slave in this case. Does Artemis support master to master failover? If yes, can any one provide the broker configuration. Currently I have defined following configuration in both server's `broker.xml` file.

```xml
<ha-policy>
   <shared-store>
      <master>
         <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
      </master>
   </shared-store>
</ha-policy>
```

Also, if possible can you please provide the sample client code for test the master to master failover scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Failover support in ActiveMQ Artemis is provided by a master/slave pair as that is the only configuration where two brokers have the same journal data (either via shared-storage or replication). Failover between one master and another master is not supported.